# Initializing array inside class gives std::bad_alloc error, but outside doesn't?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, bad-alloc

I have a program with two classes (I'll call them Master and Slave), with Slave inheriting from Master. In Slave, I defined a struct, and an array of possible values of this struct type. Slave is then instantiated with the index of the array whose values I want to fill variables from the Master class.

Like so:

```
class Master
{
public:
    std::string _a;
    char _b;
    int _c;
    int _d;
    int _e;

    Master(std::string a, char b, int c, int d, int e)
        : _a {a}, _b {b}, _c {c}, _d {d}, _e {e} {}
};

class Slave : public Master
{
public:
    struct SlaveStruct
    {
        std::string a;
        char b;
        int c;
        int d;
        int e;
    };

    const SlaveStruct slaveArray[3]
    {
        {"name_a", 'A', 1, 2, 3},
        {"name_b", 'B', 4, 5, 6},
        {"name_c", 'C', 7, 8, 9}
    };

    Slave(int index) : Master {slaveArray[index].a, slaveArray[index].b, 
        slaveArray[index].c, slaveArray[index].d, slaveArray[index].e} {}
};
```

This, however, gives off a std::bad_alloc error when I try to instantiate it. Messing around, I found it works perfectly fine however if I just declare the array inside the class, and initialize it outside, as such:

```
class Slave : public Master
{
    //(...)

    static SlaveStruct slaveArray[3];

    //(...)
};

Slave::SlaveStruct Slave::slaveArray[3]
{
    {"name_a", 'A', 1, 2, 3},
    {"name_b", 'B', 4, 5, 6},
    {"name_c", 'C', 7, 8, 9}
};
```

Why is that, however? This array is 144 bytes in size, it should barely make a dent in the stack, and I'm only instantiating the class once. Tried debugging it, but after stepping in the Slave constructor it goes into a deep rabbit-hole of C++ native functions which I can't make sense of, and soon the bad_alloc error is thrown.

**UPDATE**: As per requested in comments, class is instantiated as such:

```
int main()
{
    Slave slave {1}; // For example, any index will throw the same error.
}
```

Platforms: Windows 10, MSVC 2017.

Comment: Please show how you instantiate the bad version.

Comment: You should to initialize `slaveArray` inside the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base class constructor is called first, then members are constructed.

In `Master {slaveArray[index].a,...}`, you are trying to pass `slaveArray[index].a` to the base class' constructor, but at this point `slaveArray` is not initialized yet. Your program therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

In contrast, the static member is initialized at program startup, before `main` is entered. That's why your second example works fine.

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik, that was quite insightful!